# Navigation buttons appear over the close box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The *Questions/Tags/Users/Badges/Unanswered* navigation buttons appear over the close box.  I am using Firefox 3.6, Mac OS.

Because the close box is vertically centered, you need to make your viewport vertically almost as short as the close box itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment